# OPA Gatekeeper Policy to block priviliged Pods

Tags: kubernetes, opa, open-policy-agent

Since 2 days I try to create a simple OPA Gatekeeper Policy which blocks the creation of pods with "privileged:true" for some namespaces.

Some more details:

Im using opa-gatekeeper in version 3.13 installed by following [these instructions](https://open-policy-agent.github.io/gatekeeper/website/docs/install).

To enable the policy, first I created a ConstraintTemplate:

```
apiVersion: templates.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: ConstraintTemplate
metadata:
  name: disallowprivilegedpods
  annotations:
    description: "Disallow creation of privileged pods in alpha and beta namespaces"
spec:
  crd:
    spec:
      names:
        kind: DisallowPrivilegedPods
  targets:
    - target: admission.k8s.gatekeeper.sh
      rego: |
        package disallow_privileged_pods

        violation[{"msg": msg}] {
          input.request.kind.kind == "Pod"
          input.request.operation == "CREATE"
          input.request.namespace == ["alpha", "beta"]
          input.request.object.spec.securityContext.privileged == true
          msg := "Privileged pods are not allowed in the Alpha and Beta namespaces."
        }
```

Next I created the constraint:

```
apiVersion: constraints.gatekeeper.sh/v1beta1
kind: DisallowPrivilegedPods
metadata:
  name: disallow-privileged-pods-alpha-beta
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Pod"]
    namespaces:
      - alpha
      - beta
```

To test if the policy is working correctly, I tried to deploy this pod in one of these namespaces:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: privileged-pod
  namespace: alpha
spec:
  containers:
    - name: my-container
      image: nginx
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Unfortunately the policy doesnt seem to work and the pod can be created.

Can anyone give me some hints, whats wrong with the policy?

Cheers,

Christian

Answer (score 1):

This check - `input.request.namespace == ["alpha", "beta"]` will evaluate to true only if the `input.request.namespace` field is exactly identical to the array it is being compared to. i.e. - Only if `input.request.namespace` is an array with exactly two values, the first one being "alpha" and the second one "beta"

To check if an array input field holds one of two values, use [incremental rules](https://www.eknert.com/tech/2020/02/04/incremental-rules-in-opa.html) and [array lookups](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#arrays):

```
namespace_alpha_or_beta {
    "alpha" = input.request.namespace[_]
}

namespace_alpha_or_beta {
    "beta" = input.request.namespace[_]
}
```